# log4net stops working on separate task

Tags: c#, log4net, log4net-configuration

I have this code for log4net which works for few line but stops working after that which is strange!

Here is code

```
public void SyncPR5600(int serviceId)
{
    Logger.Info("Starting execution of {0} out of task");
    Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        string tableName = "PR5600";
        Logger.Info(string.Format("Starting execution of {0}", tableName));    
    });
}
```

The first line of Logger gets logged by log4net appender but later line in Task.Factory.StratNew stops working.

Surprisingly the same code works in Console application but when moved to windows service, it stops logging.

This is so wrong!

[Update1]
Log4net config

```
<log4net>
<appender name="ErrorsLog" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
  <file value="${PROGRAMDATA}\DEVIT\eProc\" />
  <appendToFile value="true" />
  <param name="DatePattern" value="yyyy-MM-'CadRmsSyncService_Errors.log'" />
  <staticLogFileName value="false" />
  <maximumFileSize value="100GB" />
  <maxSizeRollBackups value="0" />
  <param name="Threshold" value="WARN" />
  <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
    <conversionPattern value="%d [%t] %-5p - %m%n" />
  </layout>
</appender>
<appender name="InfoLog" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
  <file value="${PROGRAMDATA}\DEVIT\eProc\" />
  <appendToFile value="true" />
  <param name="DatePattern" value="yyyy-MM-'CadRmsSyncService_Info.log'" />
  <staticLogFileName value="false" />
  <maximumFileSize value="100GB" />
  <maxSizeRollBackups value="0" />
  <param name="Threshold" value="DEBUG" />
  <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
    <conversionPattern value="%d [%t] %-5p - %m%n" />
    <IgnoresException value="False" />
  </layout>
  <filter type="log4net.Filter.LevelRangeFilter">
    <levelMin value="DEBUG" />
    <levelMax value="FATAL" />
  </filter>
</appender>
<root>
  <level value="DEBUG"/>      
  <appender-ref ref="ErrorsLog" />
  <appender-ref ref="InfoLog" />
</root>
```

Comment: Can you post your log4net configuration?

Comment: Also, what is `Logger`?

Comment: @pixelbadger  See update in question

Comment: @Matan Shahar - It internally uses log4net for logging. It's a common class for logging.

Comment: By default ProgramData has restricted permissions - a file created by one user cannot be modified by another. And by default a Windows Service will run as a different user to your own Windows account. Can you delete the existing logfile and then run your Windows service *without* running it as a console app first?

Comment: @pixelbadger - The code works until first logger line and then stops for the rest

Answer (score 0):

My code works with the TaskCreationOptions.AttachedToParent option. Interestingly running in VS2017 debug mode produces the log even without the option.

```
public static readonly log4net.ILog log = log4net.LogManager.GetLogger(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);

...

Task.Factory.StartNew<Model>(() =>
{
    //My Work that writes log
}, TaskCreationOptions.AttachedToParent).ContinueWith((t) =>
{
    //Update UI code using that also writes log
}, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
```